# Does MySQL SHOW command count for wait_timeout?

Tags: mysql, timeout

Do `SHOW` commands such as:

```
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout'
```

reset the [`wait_timeout` in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)?

Answer (score 1):

They doesn't really reset the `wait_timeout` value but they do reset the "time since last command" so doing `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES` often enough would prevent the server to close the connection. So would `SELECT 1`.